# Serverless Lambda loading information from separate YAML file

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to separate my environment variables from being directly implemented within my `serverless.yml` file and read that I can use a separate yaml or json file and pull values from those files with the command `${file(./file.yml):property}`, but despite following this procedure I receive an error message related to the `environment:` section that references these custom settings values that leads me to believe it is related to my file selection.

**Error Message:**

```
can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key in "/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/lambdas/playground/serverless.yml" at line 18, column 14:
      environment:
```

**serverless.yml** (Run in stage=dev, I have an issue. If I run this in stage=prod there is no issue.):

```
custom:
  domain:
    dev: ${file(./local-keys.yml):apiKey}
    prod: "domain.com - prod"
  apiKey:
    dev: ""
    prod: "123apikey"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: '${opt:stage, 'dev'}'
  environment:
    DOMAIN: ${self:custom.domain.${self:provider.stage}}
    API_KEY: ${self:custom.apiKey.${self:provider.stage}}
```

**local-keys.yml:**

```
apiKey: "THIS IS A TEST"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is how you are setting stage.  This works for me when I run sls print -s dev

```
service: test
custom:
  domain:
    dev: ${file(./local-keys.yml):apiKey}
    prod: "domain.com - prod"
  apiKey:
    dev: ""
    prod: "123apikey"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  environment:
    DOMAIN: ${self:custom.domain.${self:provider.stage}}
    API_KEY: ${self:custom.apiKey.${self:provider.stage}}
```

sls print -s dev outputs:

```
service: test
custom:
  domain:
    dev: THIS IS A TEST
    prod: domain.com - prod
  apiKey:
    dev: ''
    prod: 123apikey
provider:
  stage: dev
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  environment:
    DOMAIN: THIS IS A TEST
    API_KEY: ''
```

Comment: Hmm, I still receive the same error when running `sls print -s dev`. I forgot to mention that I am using serverless offline, but I don't believe that is an issue at this moment

Comment: When I change stage from `'${opt:stage, 'dev'}'` to `'dev'` it works as you mentioned. Do you know what would make the first setup incorrect? I have been using it in the project up to this point without issue

Comment: The issue is the single quotes. `'${ }'` should be `${ }`